# parent/child accounts in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, credentials

I want to make an app where parents can buy a subscription for their children (one subscription per child) but I wonder how the corresponding accounts in Firebase would look like (buying the subscriptions themselves is out of scope of this question).

Are there best practises I should follow here?

- I'll have a parent account in Firebase I guess
- how can I create the children's accounts and how do I communicate their (generated?) credentials to them?

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication maintains a flat list of accounts per project. There is no built-in relations between any of the accounts, unless they are linked (which is not what you want here).

The best I can think of for the structure is to [add a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to the child accounts identifying their parent (and vice versa if needed). This needs to be done from a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run). A [local (Node.js, or other supported language) script](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) or this [extension that sets claims based on a Firestore document](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/experimental-extensions/tree/next/firestore-auth-claims) are probably the easiest way to get started with this.

If you choose to [create the kid's accounts in a trusted environment with an Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) too, you might as well add the custom claim there.

Comment: At the risk of pushing my luck: any suggestions on where to start for the parent buying the actual subscription (on Shopify?) and for the child validating whether there is a valid subscription?

Comment: Sorry Marc, that's outside of my wheelhouse.